# How to change the height of the y-axis in a Highcharts chart when the yAxis class has been deprecated?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, axis

I currently have a `Highcharts` chart with two y-axis as shown below.

The left axis is the only one I want to change the size of. I want to reduce the height of the bars so thay appear below the spline area data series. I tried to access the `height()` method on the [`YAxis`](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis) class but this appears to be deprecated. Its replacement - [`Axis`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis) class - does not seem to offer a way to do this.

I can manipulate the json in a fiddle to achieve what I want but would much prefer to do this programatically if possible.

[image: Chart]

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor which I could work on? For now, I can only guess that maybe setting different max, for example to 8k or 9k will change it as you want. https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.max

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, after investigating further the maxpadding/minPadding worked to solve the problem.